# Upgrade sharepoint 2013 solution

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, upgrade

I have a sharpeoint solution installed. I want to install a newer version of the solution as an upgade which I did using :

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity MySolutionName.wsp –LiteralPath “C:\MySolutionName.wsp” -GACDeployment
```

This command seem to work fine as there are no errors however after I run this, the whole solution becomes uninstalled. Does anyone have any ideas on why this could be or point out where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have the files or features changed? "Use this cmdlet only if a new solution contains the same set of files and features as the deployed solution. If files and features are different, the solution must be retracted and redeployed by using the Uninstall-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution cmdlets, respectively." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Yes, I have already checked this and all files and features are the same

Answer (score 1):

Update-SPSolution is always rather tricky. We always use Uninstall-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution.